# Question on a variation of geometric distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have a problem in my mind that I can't find the right distribution/solution for, the problem is as follows:

I play a game divided into rounds, each round I flip a coin and if I get heads[50%] I get a point and another flip for that round. When I get tails the round ends.

So each round looks like a series of flips until I get tails, lets assume X-head, O-tails:

```
O - 0 point
XO - 1 points
XXO - 2 points
and so on..
```

I win the game if I get more then x point in y round. (x and y are known constants)

So I can tell that the points I get in one round are a geometric distribution with p=0.5, and the expected amount of points in one such round is 1.
But I can't formulate what can be said about the whole game. Is there a known distribution I'm missing?

**EDIT:**
changed the points to start from 0.

Comment: The probability of winning is $P(G_1+\cdots+G_y>x)$ where the $G_i$ are iid geometric with $p=0.5$. The random variable $G_1+\cdots+G_y$ has so-called [negative binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution) with parameters $r=y$ (number of failures/tails) and $p=0.5$.

Comment: Thank you! You should make it an answer so I can accept it.
Is there a smarter way then to actually calculate each P from 0 to x, it could get really messy with big numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability of winning is $P(G_1+⋯+G_y>x)$ where the $G_i$ are iid geometric with $p=0.5$.

The random variable $G_1+⋯+G_y$ has so-called [negative binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution) with parameters $r=y$ (number of failures/tails) and $p=0.5$.

We have:$$P(G_1+⋯+G_y=k)=\binom{k+y-1}{k}p^k(1-p)^y\tag1$$
so that:$$P(G_1+⋯+G_y>x)=1-\sum_{k=0}^x\binom{k+y-1}{k}p^k(1-p)^y\tag2$$
I am not familiar with any handsome calculation of $(2)$.

Answer (score 0):

drhab has given an exact solution using the negative binomial distribution

For large $y$ you can use a normal approximation, since you are summing $y$ i.i.d. copies of a random variable with mean $1$ and variance $2$.  So your approximation would be $$P(S_y > x) \approx 1 - \Phi\left(\dfrac{x+\frac12-y}{\sqrt{2y}}\right) = \Phi\left(\dfrac{y-x-\frac12}{\sqrt{2y}}\right)  $$ where $\Phi$ is the cumulative distribution function of a standard normal random variable

As an example with R, and $x=60, y=50$

```
> 1 - pnbinom(60, 50, 1/2)      # exact result
[1] 0.1471169
> pnorm((50-60-1/2)/sqrt(2*50)) # approximation
[1] 0.1468591
```